# R: ordering binary sequences e.g. 101001111

Tags: r, binary

I have a series of binary number sequences as indicator variables.  For example this

```
100000001001      
110000000000
100000000011
111000000000
100000000000
100100000110
```

may be an index for 2 other non-binary variables.

How would I order these in R (or sort them), so that this is returned with the corresponding values it indexes:

```
100000000000
110000000000
111000000000
crap I'm not interested in
```

Where "crap I'm not interested in" are the other values that are not the sequences that start with 1, continue with 1, and then have trailing zeros.  But what I have are all possible combinations, which I do not need.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making up a vector for demo purposes (the example given above):

```
x <- c("100000001001", "110000000000", "100000000011", "111000000000", "100000000000", "100100000110")
```

Grab the the interesting values with regexp:

```
notcrap <- x[grep('^[1]*[0]*$', x)]
```

Sort it:

```
> sort(notcrap)
[1] "100000000000" "110000000000" "111000000000"
```

Comment: Cool, this works nice.  One thing I left out, the special case of all zeroes I also hope to retain.  Although I can do that much by hand.

Comment: @Nate: just run the above example on a vector where you have an element with all zeros: it should work :) Eg.: `x <- c("100000001001", "110000000000", "100000000011", "111000000000", "100000000000", "100100000110", "00000000000"); notcrap <- x[grep('^[1]*[0]*$', x)]; sort(notcrap)` Sorry for crowded, one-liner example, I do not know how to use line breaks in the comment.

Comment: ....nevermind.  It does work with all zeroes.  I have to study this to figure it out- thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for speed, use this bithack to determine if an int x is "crap" or not

```
bool notCrap(int x) {
    int y = ~x;
    return (y & (y-1)) == 0;
}
```